# How to download Images from a dynamic website using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm learning automation these days. **So I was wondering if there any way I can download images from a dynamic website using Selenium**? I'm using Java for this.

I'm able to get the links to about 40 images but not all. I don't know how dynamic website works but I think some of the links gets loaded/shown when the user is scrolling through the page or something like that!

Comment: You can scroll until stop loading new images or until meet a condition.

Comment: Hi Raul1ro thanks for answering. Yes I'm doing that but I'm only able to get maximum 43 images no matter how much I scroll down.
Is there any parallel image downloading process. I mean download images that are being shown and after finishing that, Scroll down and repeat the process.

Comment: Why do you need to download images using Selenium? What is your scenario for this?

Comment: demouser123
Actually I&#39;m not particularly downloading images using Selenium, I need all the image links and the rest can be downloaded using simple Java. So the image links are dynamic, is there any way I can get all the image links?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this method

```
/**
 * @author mbn
 * @Date 05/11/2018
 * @Purpose This method will download file from url
 * @param href
 *            --> The hyper link of the file we want to download
 * @param fileName
 *            --> the name of the file
 * @return N/A
 * @Note Path is set to .//OutputData// and will need to be chnaged as per your
 *       need
 */
public static void downloadFile(String href, String fileName) throws Exception {

    URL url = null;
    URLConnection con = null;
    int i;
    url = new URL(href);
    con = url.openConnection();
    File file = new File(".//OutputData//" + fileName);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
        while ((i = bis.read()) != -1) {
            bos.write(i);
        }
        bos.flush();
        bis.close();
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. But I'm having the problem with dynamic loading links, Actually, I'm trying to get image links using Selenium WebDriver, which are being loaded dynamically, so I'm only getting maximum 40 img links despite the fact that I scroll the page or not. 
Thanks for answering BTW.

Comment: uwc, honestly this might be tricky, May be you will need to wait for the page to load and then you will be able to retrieve all images

Comment: Try this method for page load


 public static void waitForPageToLoad(long timeOutInSeconds) {
  log.info("Waiting for page to load");
  ExpectedCondition<Boolean> expectation = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
   public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
    return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
   }

Comment: or share the url and the code and I should figure  it out